How can I verify Volta hooks.json is valid?
I set my hooks.json in global.
{
  "node": {
    "index": {
      "template": "https://cdn.npmmirror.com/binaries/node/index.json"
    },
    "distro": {
      "template": "https://registry.npmmirror.com/-/binary/node/v{{version}}/{{filename}}"
    }
  },
  "npm": {
    "index": {
      "prefix": "https://registry.npmmirror.com/npm/"
    },
    "latest": {
      "bin": "~/npm-latest"
    },
    "distro": {
      "template": "https://registry.npmmirror.com/npm/npm-{{version}}.tgz"
    }
  }
}

But when I run
$ npm config get registry

output is still 'https://registry.npmjs.org/'.
How can I verify Volta hooks.json is valid?
It's supposed to output 'https://registry.npmmirror.com/'
